# Python - Holoviews no image

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, holoviews

I am executing the following code in Python 3.6 using the Spyder IDE as well as the Jupyter notebook in the canopy environment. The code executes fine in both the environments but I do not see any image output. Can someone guide me on how I can output or view the image.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')


hv.Sankey([
    ['A', 'X', 5],
    ['A', 'Y', 7],
    ['A', 'Z', 6],
    ['B', 'X', 2],
    ['B', 'Y', 9],
    ['B', 'Z', 4]]
).options(width=600, height=400)
```

this is the output I see

```
hv.Sankey([
    ['A', 'X', 5],
    ['A', 'Y', 7],
    ['A', 'Z', 6],
    ['B', 'X', 2],
    ['B', 'Y', 9],
    ['B', 'Z', 4]]
).options(width=600, height=400)
Out[11]: :Sankey   [start,end]   (Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python anaconda to run the Jupyter notebooks and try to execute the Program. Hope it will work.

Image Link https://i.gyazo.com/e6713a933ac73a3c2bfd159f432c4f7f.png

Comment: Same here; the original code posted works fine for me in a Jupyter notebook from the Anaconda distribution, producing output just like in that screenshot.